# Get rid of zeros after last decimal number in Python?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, formatting

I need to use precision formatting in order to bypass the default scientific notation that python gives for floats.

```
a = 0.0000435

convert = '{0:.10f}'.format(a)

print(convert)
```

**The above code produces**: 0.0000435000

However, I also need to get rid of the zeros after the last decimal number (in this case after 5). The float in variable "a" can change too so the positioning of the last decimal number might be different every time.

**E.g.** 0.0000005100, 0.00205437000 etc.

Comment: `.rstrip("0")`?

Comment: but you are specifically asking for 10 decimal digits in your code. `{0:.10f}`

Comment: Why format it with 10 decimal digits in the first place? Just `print(a)` directly.

Comment: The conclusion from the duplicate question appears to be that `'{0:.15f}'.format(a).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')` is the best solution. I'm a bit baffled that there isn't a more simple solution using only `format`.

Comment: @blhsing I don't want scientific notation

Comment: @Stef '{0:.15f}'.format(a).rstrip('0') seems to do the trick for me. What does the last "rstripe('.') do?

Comment: @PissedOffBanker It makes sure that `"3.0000"` becomes `"3"` and not `"3."`.

Comment: @Stef Understood, thanks so much